# Print variable before string

Tags: python

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
1) age = int(input("How old are you? "))

print((age), + ("is how old you are."))
```

Thanks

Comment: You're missing closing brackets on both lines

Comment: I just tried that, got invalid syntax. I changed the question you can see how I did it...

Comment: This question lacks details, what is the error you are getting? is `1)` parth of the program?

Answer (score 4):

```
print(str(age) + " is how old you are")
```

if you want a quick fix but please take a look at the better syntax below:

```
print("{} is how old you are".format(age))
```

`format` will take care of the... formatting for all variables so you don't need to worry about conversions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :
`age=int(input("how old are you ?"))
print(str(age)+" is how old you are.")`

Other options are to use format and f strings introduced in python 3.6

Answer (score 1):

In python2 this can be accomplished by separating the terms you want to print with a comma:

```
age = int(input("How old are you?"))
print age, "is how old you are"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to print the age , just remove the int function before input.

Answer (score 0):

Type Error: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'.

It's like saying 12 + 'hello" adding a number and string. This is a type Error. So just leave out the operand "+". It will work fine.

So it's should like this now:

print((age), "is how old you are"))

Or try other methods from answers above.

> Happy Coding!!